# É possível criar uma classe a partir de uma rotina para abertura de forms? Como?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Tenho vários formulários que vou 'instanciando' pelo evento click no toolstrip, porém parece que está ficando poluído visto que todos códigos fazem a mesma rotina mudando somente os parâmetros.

Evento para abrir e verificar se já não está aberto a tela de Cadastro - Clientes:

```
private void cadastrarToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Formulário de Cadstro de Clientes
            //Verifica se já existe o mesmo formulário aberto para não sobrecarregar de processos iguais

            bool aberto = false;

            foreach (frmCadastroClientes f in this.MdiChildren.OfType<frmCadastroClientes>()) //OfType - Filtro que retorna só o que especifiquei
                if (f.Name == "frmCadastroClientes")
                {
                    f.Activate();
                    aberto = true;
                    break;
                }

            if (!aberto)
            {

                frmCadastroClientes CadastroClientes = new frmCadastroClientes();
                CadastroClientes.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                CadastroClientes.MdiParent = this;
                CadastroClientes.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                CadastroClientes.Show();
            }
        }
```

Evento para abrir e verificar se já não está aberto a tela de Cadastro - Fornecedores:

```
 private void cadastrarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Formulário de Cadastro de Fornecedores
            //Verifica se já existe o mesmo formulário aberto para não sobrecarregar de processos iguais

            bool aberto = false;

            foreach (frmCadastroFornecedores f in this.MdiChildren.OfType<frmCadastroFornecedores>()) //OfType - Filtro que retorna só o que especifiquei
                if (f.Name == "frmCadastroFornecedores")
                {
                    f.Activate();
                    aberto = true;
                    break;
                }

            if (!aberto)
            {

                frmCadastroFornecedores CadastroFornecedores = new frmCadastroFornecedores();
                CadastroFornecedores.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                CadastroFornecedores.MdiParent = this;
                CadastroFornecedores.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                CadastroFornecedores.Show();
            }
        }
```

E assim vai.. em outras telas também.

Como poderia, se possível simplificar esta rotina repetida?

Comment: É possível sim usando [*generics*](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ykkp7L), mas é preciso isto tudo aí? Alguma coisa me diz que tem solução melhor.

Comment: @Maniero Está maneira está me atendendo até o momento.. não sei se é a melhor ou pior solução, sobre o generics que você envio, eu não entendo como vou adaptar o código, ali você usou console etc

Comment: Atender e ser certo não coisa diferentes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível utilizando `Generics`. Você cria um método genérico que recebe um `Form`, o método sabe que é um `Form`, então você consegue manipula-lo.
O código fica muito mais simples.

**Método Genérico:**

```
public void CreateMdiChildOrActivate<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
    var form = this.MdiChildren.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (form == null || form.IsDisposed)
    {
        form = new T();
        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        form.MdiParent = this;
        form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        form.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        form.Activate();
    }
}
```

**Utilização:**

```
private void cadastrarToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CreateMdiChildOrActivate<frmCadastroClientes>();
}
```

**Explicação:**

```
var form = this.MdiChildren.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Eu procuro na lista de forms abertos `MdiChildren` uma instância do form tipo genérico `T` (`OfType<T>`), dependendo de quem estiver chamando, `T` pode ser um `frmCadastroPessoa`, `frmCadastroFornecedor`, `frmCadastroCachorro`, etc...

```
if (form == null || form.IsDisposed)
```

Se o form não for achado (`null`) ou tiver sido eliminado (`disposed`), eu crio um novo (`new T()`).

```
else
{
    form.Activate();
}
```

Se ele foi achado, quer dizer que ele já existe, então é só ativar ele.

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9870872/4343335)

Comment: Seria possível você me explicar o que faz a linha do 'var' exatamente a parte do .FirstOrDefault() e ali no 'if' o .isDisposed?

Comment: Pronto, no final da resposta coloquei detalhes do código.

Comment: Valeu mano, deu certinho pro que estava precisando aqui